# Confused on how to use 64-bit components installed for Delphi in C++Builder

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl, rad-studio

I'm a bit confused on adding something called StyleControls for RAD Studio.

I heard that if you install it on the Delphi version, you can also use it with C++Builder. So I compiled the source of StyleControls for Delphi 32-bit and installed it. I added its sources to the Library path options of the IDE. And everything works fine on the Delphi side for both 32-bit and 64-bit.

The issue is, when I go over to C++Builder, 32-bit works just fine, but not 64-bit, for some reason. When I change to 64-bit for a VCL application for C++Builder, and try to compile it with, let's say, a button from StyleControls from the pallet, it gives me an error:

> [bcc64 Fatal Error] Unit1.h(10): 'scControls.hpp' file not found

So, I looked around and found that when I compiled StyleControls in Delphi, it also gave me the `.hpp` at the path: "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\hpp\Win32".

So, I added it in my project options "Include file search path", which seems to fix that issue, I guess. I tried recompiling again for 64-bit, but I get another error:

> [ilink64 Error] Fatal: Invalid object file 'C:\USERS\PUBLIC\DOCUMENTS\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\22.0\DCP\STYLECONTROLS_D11ALEXANDRIA.BPI'

So, I'm not sure how to deal with this. What is the proper way to do this? How can I use StyleControls for C++Builder for 64-bit?

Comment: Sounds like something you should be asking the component author about. But, the first thing that comes to mind - when compiling the component for Delphi 64bit, is it configured to output C++ files? Seems like it is not, since you didn't find the 64bit hpp file.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the issue.

For Delphi, compiling only the 32-bit is fine, which lets you use 64-bit as well. But, if you want to use 64-bit in C++Builder, you have to select the "Generate for C++Builder (with libs)" option in "Project/Options/Delphi Compiler/Output - C/C++".

I selected a folder for the 64-bit. Little tip for those trying to compile 64-bit for StyleControls in Delphi: make sure you put for the `requires` of the .dpk: `{$IFDEF WIN32}designide,{$ENDIF}`
As well for the `contains` field for: `{$IFDEF WIN32}scPReg in 'scPReg.pas',{$ENDIF}`. After adding these, it let me build for 64-bit and the generatd `.hpp`, `.bpi`, and so on are placed in the folder I specified.

After you have all the generated files for C++Builder, go into "tools/options/language/C++/path and directories", find the "Library paths" and MAKE SURE FOR 64-bit, add the folder where you generated all the C++Builder files when compiling.

If it gives you the same error I got, like "[ilink64 Error] Fatal: Invalid object file 'C:\USERS\PUBLIC\DOCUMENTS\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\22.0\DCP\STYLECONTROLS_D11ALEXANDRIA.BPI'", that means you put the 32-bit path for the BPI, removing it should solve the issue.